# If the value of ng-app is not empty string the angular directives are not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-app

I am new to AngularJs. I am just getting confused why does my code when the value for ng-app is just empty string the Angular directives are working but on the other hand the directives are not working if the its value is not empty string.

What is happening here? My code is below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loginPage.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body **ng-app="loginApp"** class="body-bg-blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
                    <div class="login-form">

                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h1>STWEBAPP</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div **ng-controller="loginController"**>

                            <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required />
                                    <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$dirty && loginForm.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                                    <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn-danger">Login</button>
                                    <img ng-if="dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your directive code as well

Comment: done updating! :)

Comment: still i dont see any directive in the code

Comment: it's the ng-show that's not working if ng-app and/or ng-controller has value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about ng-app directive, if you declare `ng-app` int he application with a name , you need the module to be declared.

```
 var app = angular.module("loginApp", []);
 app.controller("loginController", ["$scope",
 function($scope) {


 }
]);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("loginApp", []);

app.controller("loginController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
  
        
  }
]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loginPage.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="loginApp" class="body-bg-blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
                    <div class="login-form">

                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h1>STWEBAPP</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div ng-controller="loginController">

                            <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required />
                                    <span ng-show="loginForm.username.$dirty && loginForm.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                                    <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn-danger">Login</button>
                                    <img ng-if="dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAP///wAAAMLCwkJCQgAAAGJiYoKCgpKSkiH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh/hpDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggYWpheGxvYWQuaW5mbwAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi63P4wyklrE2MIOggZnAdOmGYJRbExwroUmcG2LmDEwnHQLVsYOd2mBzkYDAdKa+dIAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADNAi63P5OjCEgG4QMu7DmikRxQlFUYDEZIGBMRVsaqHwctXXf7WEYB4Ag1xjihkMZsiUkKhIAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzYIujIjK8pByJDMlFYvBoVjHA70GU7xSUJhmKtwHPAKzLO9HMaoKwJZ7Rf8AYPDDzKpZBqfvwQAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzMIumIlK8oyhpHsnFZfhYumCYUhDAQxRIdhHBGqRoKw0R8DYlJd8z0fMDgsGo/IpHI5TAAAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzIIunInK0rnZBTwGPNMgQwmdsNgXGJUlIWEuR5oWUIpz8pAEAMe6TwfwyYsGo/IpFKSAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi6IMKQORfjdOe82p4wGccc4CEuQradylesojEMBgsUc2G7sDX3lQGBMLAJibufbSlKAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMgi63P7wCRHZnFVdmgHu2nFwlWCI3WGc3TSWhUFGxTAUkGCbtgENBMJAEJsxgMLWzpEAACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAAQABAAAAMyCLrc/jDKSatlQtScKdceCAjDII7HcQ4EMTCpyrCuUBjCYRgHVtqlAiB1YhiCnlsRkAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA=="/>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```